# concat columns including reserve word

Tags: mysql, concatenation, reserved-words

```
select concat(Sno,Table) as STB from levels
```

Above query gives error if run as it is. Say i have valuse in levels as

```
Sno   Table
1     Sale
2     Stock
```

I need to fetch them as

```
STB
---
1Sale
2Stock
```

What can be the solution `other than changing the column name` because putting quotes around the word `'Table'` gives the wrong output as it becomes just a string

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses and special thanks to @Tenner. I accepted the other solution because of first came and low repo was also a bit factor, hope so tenner would not mind because there is also a first come reason as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ` instead of ' like this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(Sno,`Table`) AS STB FROM levels
```

Comment: Hope you have read my last statement `because putting quotes around the word 'Table' gives the wrong output as it becomes just a string`

Comment: I am sorry it was a very stupid question. Don't know why i missed to try  backtick which I usually use rather than quotes. But thanks now I came to know the difference, and very foolish that i had been told that they are same and I never tried to look for the difference. Thanks a lot

Comment: Haha no problem, it's a common mistake, but stop using reserved words. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks for reserved words.

```
select concat(Sno, `Table`) as STB from levels
```

Though in general, if you can avoid using reserved words for database, table, or column names in the future, that's a good idea.

Comment: Hope you have read my last statement `because putting quotes around the word 'Table' gives the wrong output as it becomes just a string`

Comment: That's not a quote, that's a backtick. If you're on a US keyboard, it's below the tilde character (~), probably next to the 1 key at the upper left.

Comment: I am sorry it was a very stupid question. Don't know why i missed to try  backtick which I usually use rather than quotes. But thanks now I came to know the difference, and very foolish that i had been told that they are same and I never tried to look for the difference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

```
select concat(Sno,`Table`) as STB 
from levels
```

Comment: Hope you have read my last statement `because putting quotes around the word 'Table' gives the wrong output as it becomes just a string`

Comment: I am sorry it was a very stupid question. Don't know why i missed to try  backtick which I usually use rather than quotes. But thanks now I came to know the difference, and very foolish that i had been told that they are same and I never tried to look for the difference. Thanks a lot